# Cannot find the object because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

Trying to do a simple

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.sp_add_job TO [user]

GO
```

and I am getting

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object 'sp_add_job', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Completion time: 2023-03-20T13:48:36.6851327-04:00
```

I am sysadmin, and true enough, I cannot locate the SP, but I thought that the SP_Add_job was auto created, or was I incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions to the Server Agent's procedures are given by adding user to one of the [fixed database roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles):

- SQLAgentUserRole
- SQLAgentReaderRole
- SQLAgentOperatorRole

Granting execute permission on a specific procedure is incorrect.